# AOSP: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK

Tags: android, apk, android-source, android.mk

### I'm facing the below error while installing the apk which is built on the Android-12 version of the AOSP repo and installing this apk on the Android-11 version of the System image
error:

C:\Users\test\Desktop\Radio_prio>adb install test.apk
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install test.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl956026352.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #10): Requires newer sdk version #31 (current version is #30)]